# Remove command injection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, brakeman

So I have a helper that uses `ImageMagick` and a method inside it which  enforces `zbar` on command line to extract QR data from an image. The image source  has to be parametric.

```
qr_code_data = %x(zbarimg -q #{src})
```

`brakeman` gives me a `command injection` warning here, obviously. Using only `backticks` gives the same warning, and while `system` would produce the result required, it returns `true` and not the output. I don't want to use a QR-decoding wrapper/gem, or Open3. I need to know can I sanitise my image source as a parameter to avoid command injection, except by using the two options I have mentioned.

Comment: ImageMagick generally supports using STDIN for input. Try `zbarimg -q png:-`. Replace `png` with your actual image format. Then use [IO.popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-popen) instead of `system`. I'm not 100% certain that this will work and do not have a suitable test system ready. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick generally supports using STDIN for input. IO.popen supports replacing stdin of the subprocess with the contents of a file. Try the following:

```
qr_code_data = ""
IO.popen(['zbarimg','-q','png:-'], :in=>[src]) do |pipe|
  qr_code_data = pipe.read
end
```

Replace `png` above with your actual image format or remove `png:` entirely to allow ImageMagick to determine the file type from the input's magic number.

Comment: That helped. Thank You